# Run R code inside stargazer function

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, stargazer

I have a code chunk in a .Rnw file like this:

```
<<test, results = "asis">>=

stargazer(mtcars, notes = c($n$ = \\Sexpr{nrow(mtcars)})

@
```

When I use `knitr` to evaluate the R code and convert the .Rnw file to a .tex file, how can I get `nrow(mtcars)` to evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<test, results = "asis">>=
library("stargazer")
stargazer(mtcars, notes = paste('$n$ = ',nrow(mtcars)))
@

\end{document}
```

You can't put an `Sexpr` inside a code chunk.